# How to do "getline" from a std::string?

Tags: c++, string, stream, getline

I have a problem. I load the whole file and then getline through it to get some info. However in the map format there may be 0 or 20 "lines" with the info. I need to know how to getline through std::string. There is a function (source stream, destination string, decimal) but I need (source string, destination string, decimal). Searching in streams isn't possible in C++ (only using many temp string and extracting and inserting many times, it's unclear and I don't want to do it that messy way). So I want to know how to getline from a std::string.

Thans

Answer (score 33):

You seem to want [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream), which is in the header [`<sstream>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/):

```
std::string some_string = "...";

std::istringstream iss(some_string);

std::string line;
while (std::getline(iss, line))
{
    // Do something with `line`
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Simple question related to it. How to make getline NOT to get a line when there is no decimal found in the stream?

Comment: Because that's still a problem as I can't search in a stream (that's why I wanted string getline which doesn't exist).

Comment: @user1873947 The simplest is probably to check if the string you use contains a digit, and then skip the whole `std::istringstream`/`std::getline` bit.